# How can I implement the Android camera to take photos in any screen orientation?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'd like the orientation of the camera not to change when the phone is rotated, allowing the camera to take an upright picture in any orientation. Currently, the picture is rotated incorrectly in all orientations except for one. Tested on an HTC Incredible running 2.2:

- Portrait mode has the image rotated 90 degrees clockwise of what it should be.
- Device rotated counterclockwise from portrait yields an image rotated 180 degrees.
- Device rotated clockwise from portrait yields an image with correct orientation.

Here is the relevant code for the camera implementation:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    // Set up camera's SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_surface);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    p.setPreviewSize(width,height);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        camera.release();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Since I'd like the application to be compatible with any API level equal to or above 4 to maximize user base, I'd prefer if answers didn't use anything specific to higher API levels. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the preview also to rotate then set the orientation to landscape or portrait mode in your manifest file.

To get correctly rotated images you need to call the setRotation() (API level 5) on the camera parameter and then set that parameter just before you call the takePicture API. You will also need to use orientationEventListener

Sample code [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I think it's bug. I've got this problem too, but in my situation I can't find anything.

This code can be correct and maybe must help you when u using camera preview.

If not - this code not help you. I'm using without camera so it's not helping me.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)  
{
    try
    {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;

    int previewSurfaceWidth = preview.getWidth();
    int previewSurfaceHeight = preview.getHeight();

    LayoutParams lp = preview.getLayoutParams();


    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        // ïîðòðåòíûé âèä
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        lp.height = previewSurfaceHeight;
        lp.width = (int) (previewSurfaceHeight / aspect);
    }
    else
    {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        lp.width = previewSurfaceWidth;
        lp.height = (int) (previewSurfaceWidth / aspect);
    }

    preview.setLayoutParams(lp);
    camera.startPreview();


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, setDisplayOrientation only works for API level 8 and above: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29)

Comment: the alternative to setDisplayOrientation for older API versions is Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.set("rotation", degrees);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of any screen orientation, including different handling for front and back camera:

```
// Set camera rotation (consider display orientation)
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int displayOrientation = display.getRotation();

int rotation = cameraInfo.orientation;
if (Surface.ROTATION_0 != displayOrientation)
{
    if (CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK == cameraInfo.facing)
    {
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation -= 90;
        }
        else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation -= 180;
        }
        if (Surface.ROTATION_270 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation -= 270;
        }

        if (rotation < 0)
        {
            rotation += 360;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation += 90;
        }
        else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation += 180;
        }
        if (Surface.ROTATION_270 == displayOrientation)
        {
            rotation += 270;
        }

        rotation %= 360;
    }
}

Log.d(TAG, "Camera orientation (" + cameraInfo.orientation + ", " + displayOrientation + ", " + rotation + ")");

cameraParams.setRotation(rotation);
```